# export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH Does not seem to work. Even after setting the working directory, package not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I tried to find the rospack, get the following error.
[rospack] Error: stack/package set_Goals not found

I have pasted the ~/.bashrc file below.

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source ~/ros_ws/devel/setup.bash
source ~/ros_ws/devel/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/madhu/rosPractice:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

I seriously dont know where I have been going wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/124126/export-ros_package_path-does-not-seem-to-work.-even-after-setting-the-working-directory,-package-not-found/) by [maddy_nish](https://answers.ros.org/users/11426/maddy_nish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try a rospack profile

---

Originally posted by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) with karma: 296 on 2014-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0